# How can I locate the water main entry point to my house?

Tags: plumbing

I live in a single story all side brick ranch home in Austin, TX built in 1997.
I am planning to put a whole house water filter to the the main water supply line coming into the house from the water meter. Does anyone know where to look for? I have a suspicion that it might be coming in from the concrete slab, if this is true I do not have access to it. I might have to put the water filter at the cold line going into water heater, so only hot water is filtered. But I am surprised how a builder can build a property without giving a direct access to main water line for future enhancements like installing a water softener or a filter. Just wanted to double check if I am missing something here. Is it better to just hire a plumber if I need to dig into the slab for access to water line?

Update:
I am planning to dig along the exterior wall where I have the outside garden hose spigot, to look for the water line, if I find it then I will drill through the brick wall and bring the line to connect the filters.

Comment: Even if it comes into the slab, it must also come out of the slab....

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25233/how-do-i-find-the-water-main-entry-point-to-my-house)

Comment: All pipes have to start somewhere.  The question is where does it start in your house and do you have room to put a filter there.

Comment: I see an access panel right next to my guest bathroom, when I open it, it shows a copper pipe come out of the slab going up along side the bath tub into my attic to the water heater, but i am not sure if this is the primary entry point? I am suspecting that similar pipe from slab might be given for kitchen and master bathroom.

Comment: Have you checked the garage? In the US you can usually "call before you dig" and someone will trace all the lines on the property. Tell them you're going to install sprinklers around the footprint. It's free in my area but possibly in general.

Comment: I opened up the dry wall from inside garage and see the outside hose bib connects to the pipe under slab

Answer (score 1):

Is there a water shut off at the street? Should be a small manhole, maybe 6" wide. You should be able to follow that in a straight line to your house. From that point, inside or outside of your house, you should be able to find a copper pipe and a ball valve. Maybe the copper surfaces above the slab for an indoor shutoff, and you could attach the filter there.